# Shouldn't reading a stream, end it?

Tags: c#, stream, asp.net-web-api2, outputstream, action-filter

Why reading `Response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` doesn't prevent writing output to the client?

Summary: I have an `ActionFilter` in an `ASP.NET WebAPI 2` application, which I'm reading the entire output-stream in `ActionExecuted` event. This is the sample code:

```
var content = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
byte[] buffer = new byte[content.Length];
content.Read(buffer, 0, (int)content.Length);
```

What I'm expecting after that, is an *empty-output*, but the entire output is going to the client after all. What am I missing here? Shouldn't reading a stream, end it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't empty the response after calling that method, it just serializes the response and returns a **Stream** that represents the serialized content (see [HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpContent_ReadAsStreamAsync))

If you want to clear the response, you could try to set the value of the response's `Content` property to a new instance of one of the classes derived from [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Hope it helps!